# Teclado espremendo os componentes

Tags: react-native

Quando eu clico no TextInput, as imagens ficam espremidas:

[image]

Como corrigir?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Text, View, TouchableHighlight, ImageBackground, TextInput, Image, Picker} from 'react-native';
import {Button} from 'react-native-elements';

class Consulta extends Component{
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state={
  ambiente:0,
  busca:''
}
}


  render(){
return(
  <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection:'row'}}>


    <View style={{flex:5}}>
      <ImageBackground style={{flex:1, width: null, height: null}} source={require('../img/bg.png')}>

        <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection:'row'}}>
          <View style={{flex:1}}></View>

          <View style={{flex:10, flexDirection:'column'}}>
            <View style={{flex:1}}></View>

            <View style={{flex:2, justifyContent:'center'}}>
              <Text style={{fontSize:50, color:'#484b4c'}}>CONSULTA DE FLORES</Text>
            </View>

            <View style={{flex:2, justifyContent:'center'}}>
              <Text style={{fontSize:20, color:'#484b4c', marginBottom:10}}>NOME OU CÓDIGO</Text>
              <TextInput
                style={{height:60, borderColor:'gray', borderWidth:1, backgroundColor:'white', borderRadius:10}}
                onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({busca: text})}
              />
            </View>

            <View style={{flex:5, justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'flex-start'}}>
              <View>
              <Text style={{fontSize:20, color:'#484b4c', marginBottom: 10}}>TIPO DE AMBIENTE</Text>
              </View>

              <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection:'row'}}>

              <View style={{flex:1}}>
                <TouchableHighlight style={{flex:1}}
                  onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Consulta')}>
                  <Image
                    style={{flex:1.1, width: null, height: null}}
                    source={require('../img/icone/ambiente1.png')}
                  />
                </TouchableHighlight>
                <View style={{alignItems:'center'}}>
                  <Text style={{fontSize:20}}>INTERNO</Text>
                </View>
              </View>

              <View style={{flex:1}}>
                <TouchableHighlight style={{flex:1}}
                  onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Consulta')}>
                  <Image
                    style={{flex:1.1, width: null, height: null}}
                    source={require('../img/icone/ambiente2.png')}
                  />
                </TouchableHighlight>
                <View style={{alignItems:'center'}}>
                  <Text style={{fontSize:20}}>EXTERNO</Text>
                </View>
              </View>

              <View style={{flex:1}}>
                <TouchableHighlight style={{flex:1}}
                  onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Consulta')}>
                  <Image
                    style={{flex:1.1, width: null, height: null}}
                    source={require('../img/icone/ambiente3.png')}
                  />
                </TouchableHighlight>
                <View style={{alignItems:'center'}}>
                  <Text style={{fontSize:20}}>INTERNO E EXTERNO</Text>
                </View>
              </View>

              </View>

            </View>

            <View style={{flex:3, flexDirection:'row'}}>

              <View style={{flex:1, justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
              <Button
                large
                backgroundColor='#d0e25f'
                buttonStyle={{borderRadius:20}}
                textStyle={{fontSize:40, color:'#383838'}}
                iconRight={{name:'search', type:'font-awesome', size:40, color:'#383838'}}
                title='PESQUISAR'
                onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Resultado', {busca: this.state.busca})}
              />
              </View>

            </View>

            <View style={{flex:1}}></View>
          </View>

          <View style={{flex:1}}></View>
        </View>

      </ImageBackground >
    </View>

    <View style={{flex:1}}>

      <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <TouchableHighlight style={{flex:1}}
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Consulta')}>
          <Image
            style={{flex:1, width: null, height: null}}
            source={require('../img/consultaOn.png')}
          />
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>

      <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <TouchableHighlight style={{flex:1}}
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('FormaPagamento')}>
          <Image
            style={{flex:1, width: null, height: null}}
            source={require('../img/formaOff.png')}
          />
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>

      <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <TouchableHighlight style={{flex:1}}
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Organizacao')}>
          <Image
            style={{flex:1, width: null, height: null}}
            source={require('../img/organizacaoOff.png')}
          />
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>

      <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <TouchableHighlight style={{flex:1}}
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Horario')}>
          <Image
            style={{flex:1, width: null, height: null}}
            source={require('../img/horarioOff.png')}
          />
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>

    </View>

  </View>
);
}
}

export default Consulta;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode configurar o `windowSoftInputMode` para `adjustPan` no arquivo Android manifest.

```
<manifest>
  ...

  <application>
    ...

    <activity
      ...
      android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
```

Veja a documentação [documentação](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft):

> The activity's main window is not resized to make room for the soft keyboard. Rather, the contents of the window are automatically panned so that the current focus is never obscured by the keyboard and users can always see what they are typing.